# To send a custom Message from Parent Dialog Box to child Dialog Box using SendMessage() function

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

There are several ways to use **SendMessage()**

1. WIN32API modal

> ::SendMessage(h, MY_MSG ,0,0);

2. MFC modal

   Let's ptr  having child Dialog box Handle then we can use this modal

> ptr->SendMessage(MY_MSG,0,0);

But How can I get child dialog Box handle once I clicked a button in parent Dialog box [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew61P.png).. I write the code

```
 void CCustomMessageDlg::OnBnClickedOpen(){   

     MyDialog2 d2(IDD_CHILD_DIALOG);
     d2.DoModal();

         }
```

I Need Send Custom Message to child Dialog using SendMessage() API once Button is clicked. Can You Please Suggest A solution for this problem

Comment: `DoModal` doesn't return until the dialog is dismissed. By the time it returns, the dialog is gone - there's no window to send a message to. What are you really trying to achieve? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise?

Comment: The code you've written doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a message to the dialog after `DoModal()` returns, because the dialog will already be destroyed.

In case you want to pass data to the dialog, you can add a member variable to your child dialog, say:

```
CString m_strMyData;
```

Then use:

```
 MyDialog2 d2(IDD_CHILD_DIALOG);
 d2.m_strMyData = "Test";
 d2.DoModal();
```

and access `m_strMyData` from within the child dialog.

Comment: ds Thanks for pointing out my foolish error. But Please suggest me How can I send a Custom message to the Child Dialog Box from Main Dialog

Comment: @sumanreddy - How would you trigger the sending of that message? You can't press a button on your main dialog while the child (modal)dialog is open. Maybe you need a modeless dialog?